# scandit sdk cause ios simulator build to fail

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

Env: IOS, cordova 5.0, scandit-barcodescanner-community-phonegap_4.8.2, xcode 6.3.2

I recently install the scandit plugin - I downloaded the zip scandit-barcodescanner-community-phonegap_4.8.2.zip

unzip it and installed it

> cordova plugin add  /Users/joti/Downloads/scandit-barcodescanner-community-phonegap_4.8.2

When I run it on the device (iphone 4) it works great

But I can't seem to use the simulator any more - I get build fail with msg

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

on a different project I have scandit version 1.1.0 which works with no problem on simulator/device

But I don't have the original zip I use for the install any more.

I tried to remove the plugin - the simulator was working again - until I added the plugin back

help.

Answer (score 0):

downgrade to scandit-barcodescanner-community-phonegap_4.8.1 solve the problem